# Converting an SQL query with multiple joins on join and unions to LINQ?

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, entity-framework

I am attempting to write a LINQ query that gathers information from 5 different entities, and creates a list of their information accordingly. Unfortunately, while I can get the query to work in SQL, I'm somewhat unsure how to get it to work in LINQ.

Essentially, I'm trying to get a list of all our assets (spread across two tables). I then need to go to our `AssetActions` entity and ensure that the last action performed on a particular asset is a check-in OR ensure it has never been entered in the tracking at all.

I have a final table that is called `DeviceTypes`. Only one of my asset tables uses this, the other simply auto-assigns the value `Phone`.

My working SQL Query is:

```
SELECT comp.id, 
       dType.devicetypename, 
       comp.notes 
FROM   asset.computer comp 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN asset.devicetype dType 
                    ON dType.id = comp.devicetypeid 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT t1.computerid, 
                               t1.id, 
                               t1.assetactionid 
                        FROM   asset.computertracking t1 
                               JOIN (SELECT Max(id) id, 
                                            computerid 
                                     FROM   asset.computertracking 
                                     GROUP  BY computerid) t2 
                                 ON t1.id = t2.id) track 
                    ON comp.id = track.computerid 
WHERE  track.assetactionid = 1 
        OR comp.id NOT IN(SELECT computerid 
                          FROM   asset.computertracking) 
UNION 
SELECT phone.id, 
       'Phone' AS devicetypename, 
       phone.notes 
FROM   asset.phone phone 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT t1.phoneid, 
                               t1.id, 
                               t1.assetactionid 
                        FROM   asset.phonetracking t1 
                               JOIN (SELECT Max(id) id, 
                                            phoneid 
                                     FROM   asset.phonetracking 
                                     GROUP  BY phoneid) t2 
                                 ON t1.id = t2.id) track 
                    ON phone.id = track.phoneid 
WHERE  track.assetactionid = 1 
        OR phone.id NOT IN(SELECT phoneid 
                           FROM   asset.phonetracking)
```

And one of my LINQ tests is:

```
availableAssets =   from comp in db.Computers
                    join compType in db.DeviceTypes
                    on comp.DeviceTypeId equals compType.Id
                    join track in db.ComputerTrackings
                    on comp.Id equals track.ComputerId into comp2
                    from track2 in comp2.DefaultIfEmpty()
                    where track2 == null || track2.AssetActionId == 1
                    select new AvailableAsset {
                        assetName = comp.Id.ToString(),
                        assetType = compType.DeviceTypeName,
                        assetNotes = comp.Notes
                    };
```

The main issue with the LINQ query is that while it does select the correct asset, it does not handle assets that have been entered into tracking twice. So if something was checked-out. Then checked-in. Then checked back out, it will not understand to grab the last entered record.

On a side-note. If there is any method to modify the query to return a formatted Id for the `assetName` field, it would be much appreciated. For example, it returns `1, 2, 3, 4...` now. I would like it to return `LHE-001, LHE-002...` and for phones return `LHE-TEL-001, LHE-TEL-002...`.

Comment: have you though about a tool called `LinqPad` or any other 3rd party tool that can convert Sql Queries to Linq

Comment: I've attempted several different tools to no avail.

Comment: could it be that your original query may need some refactoring do you have a `DBA` that can perhaps optimize your query..

Comment: Unfortunately not. No.

Comment: You could put all your SQL in a stored procedure and then have your EF call the stored Proc to get the data. This way you let SQL do the hard work, which currently works as required, and your code can pull the dataset in the right format.

Comment: I would prefer to have it stored in my View Model. I need to keep as many of my functions off of SQL server as possible and have them in code where possible.

Comment: @Jdsfighter is there a real reason why you would want to do that ..just curious ..why fight the powers that may be..?

Comment: Encapsulation. The application may be redeployed at any given moment, and we're trying to have it all setup so that EF can auto deploy and build the database at will. It's also considerably more simple for me personally to do everything in one place and not have to worry about maintaining both the DB and the code-base.

Comment: if that's the case, why not create the stored procedure in EF itself using `Sql("CREATE STORED PROCEDURE blah blah blah")`? Best of both worlds... you can always use the same technique to alter it in a later migration.

Comment: I guess it just comes down to personal preference. I have quite a bit of LINQ scattered throughout my different models, and rely on it almost exclusively. I just for the sake of consistency, I was looking for an alternative.